# How to refresh the NSLocale in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, refresh, currency, nslocale

I am currently working in iPhone application, Using NSLocale to get the current Currency symbol working fine, but when i press home button the app goes to background process and i change the Currency (Setting>>International>>Regionformat>>Like United states,India etc...) in this way, then open that application from background the currency symbol not changed, but i navigate to another screen then comes to previous screen only currency changed, but i want when i open the application from background, then currency symbol changed automatically. How to fix this? I need your help

Thanks

I tried code here:

```
NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
Getdollarsymbol = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
NSString *Code = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```

Comment: This may be something you can just let go. The likelihood of a real user changing their locale more than once is slim.

That said, are you running this code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear? I seem to recall there can be differences there with backgrounding. Could be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this code. And let me know if this is working,

In `-viewDidLoad:` Add Line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshCurrencySymbol) name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

then:

```
-(void) refreshCurrencySymbol
{ 
    NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *symbol = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
    NSLog(@"Symbol : %@",symbol);
    NSString *code = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSLog(@"Code : %@",code);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you match each addObserver with an equivalent removeObserver

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]
```

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) mentions

> The object always reflects the current state of the current user's locale settings.

Comment: Again the same problem is occurring.

Comment: I tried this way
[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]
NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
Getdollarsymbol = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
NSString *Code = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];